# Pointcut for all CRUD method in CrudRepository interface

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I have developed a java aspect library for logs that I import in another project. All the pointCut works well except the CRUD operation of the CrudRepository interface.
here is the pointcut used:

```java
 @Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.Repository+.*(..))")
```

Could someone tell me if this is the right pointcut or not please?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` is just a marker interface without a single method. Try the following instead:

```java
@Pointcut("execution(public * org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.*(..))")
```

Comment: it works well thanks to you my friend